# Spring Integration - Message Driven Channel Adapter Configuration To Reduce Consuming Interval

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a queue to listen messages which comes from a service like this:

```
<bean id="inboundQueue" class="com.rabbitmq.jms.admin.RMQDestination">
    <constructor-arg value="myQueue"/>
    <constructor-arg value="true"/>
    <constructor-arg value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Then, I have a message driven channel adapter like this, I can't use inbound-channel-adapter because my system has no tolerance about delay. Message forwarding and timeliness is so important.

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter  id="inboundAdaptor"
                                         auto-startup="true"
                                         connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
                                         destination="inboundQueue"
                                         channel="requestChannel"
                                         error-channel="errorHandlerChannel"
                                         receive-timeout="1000" />
```

When I started the project and checked RabbitMQ console, I saw that Get (empty) was around 10/s. Increasing or decreasing the receive-timeout property has no affect on it.

[image]

When I stopped the project, this Get (empty) is 0. I understood that the value of Get (empty) field totally about my message-driven-channel-adapter. And I guess that that time is about consuming interval about message-driven-channel-adapter.

What can I do to reduce this time?

Comment: Have you tried using a native RabbitMQ channel adapter instead of adding the JMS layer on top of it? https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-inbound-channel-adapter It is a message-driven adapter instead of pulling messages using `basicGet()`. `receiveTimeout()` has no bearing on delivery rate; it's how long the consumer thread blocks in the client waiting for data.

Comment: Hi Garry. 
Our system is based on JMSTemplate and org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory. Because of this, I can't use this. int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter requires the connection-factory as org.springframework.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory.

Comment: The native AMQP protocol is much, much, faster than JMS.